# Trying to cycle IP addresses but still getting blocked by Crunchbase when trying to scrape the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, ip

I wrote a program that scrapes funding information from Crunchbase for a list of companies using Python and BeautifulSoup. I wrote the code originally without cycling through IP addresses, and it seems like my IP address got blocked from Crunchbase because I can't even make a single request now. So, I integrated IP cycling into the program, but for some reason I'm still getting blocked by Crunchbase - could somebody point me in the right direction as to what I'm missing? I'm not too familiar with Python, I only started programming a couple of months ago so there's still a lot for me to learn. Thank you so much!

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import random


def scraper(url):
    return_list = []

    ua = UserAgent() # From here we generate a random user agent
    proxies = [] # Will contain proxies [ip, port]

    proxies_req = Request('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    proxies_req.add_header('User-Agent', ua.random)
    proxies_doc = urlopen(proxies_req).read().decode('utf8')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(proxies_doc, 'html.parser')
    proxies_table = soup.find(id='proxylisttable')

    # Save proxies in the array
    for row in proxies_table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
        proxies.append({
                'ip':   row.find_all('td')[0].string,
                'port': row.find_all('td')[1].string
                })

    for proxy in proxies:
        req = Request('http://icanhazip.com')
        req.set_proxy(proxy['ip'] + ':' + proxy['port'], 'http')

        try:
            success = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
            full_ip = proxy['ip'] + ':' + proxy['port']
            break
        except: # If error, delete this proxy and find another one
            continue

    try:
        reques = Request(url)
        reques.add_header('User-Agent', ua.random)
        reques.set_proxy(full_ip, 'http')
        response = urlopen(reques)
    except:
        return_list.append("No Crunchbase Page Found")
        return_list.append("No Crunchbase Page Found")
        print("Not found")
        print(full_ip)
    else:
        data = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

        try:
            funding_status = soup.find_all("span", class_= "component--field-formatter field-type-enum ng-star-inserted")[1].text
            return_list.append(funding_status)
        except:
            return_list.append("N/A")

        try:
            last_funding_type = soup.find("a", class_= "cb-link component--field-formatter field-type-enum ng-star-inserted").text
            if last_funding_type[:6] != "Series" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Venture" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Seed" and last_funding_type[:3] != "Pre" and last_funding_type[:5] != "Angel" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Private" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Debt" and last_funding_type[:11] != "Convertible" and last_funding_type[:5] != "Grant" and last_funding_type[:9] != "Corporate" and last_funding_type[:6] != "Equity" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Product" and last_funding_type[:9] != "Secondary" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Post" and last_funding_type[:3] != "Non" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Initial" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Funding":
                return_list.append("N/A")
            else:
                return_list.append(last_funding_type)
        except:
            return_list.append("N/A")

    return return_list


user_input = input("CSV File Name (e.g: myfile.csv): ")
user_input2 = input("New CSV file name (e.g: newfile.csv): ")
print()
scrape_file = open(user_input, "r", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(scrape_file))
scrape_file = open(user_input, "r", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")

new_file = open(user_input2, "w", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(new_file)
writer.writerow(["Company Name", "Description", "Website", "Founded", "Product Name", "Country", "Funding Status", "Last Funding Type"])

count = 0
for row in csv.reader(scrape_file):
    company_name = row[0]
    if company_name == "Company Name":
        continue

    count += 1
    print("Scraping company {} of {}".format(count, row_count))

    company_name = company_name.replace(",", "")
    company_name = company_name.replace("'", "")
    company_name = company_name.replace("-", " ")
    company_name = company_name.replace(".", " ")
    s = "-"
    join_name = s.join(company_name.lower().split())
    company_url = "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/" + join_name

    writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], scraper(company_url)[0], scraper(company_url)[1]])
    time.sleep(random.randint(30, 40))
new_file.close()
print("Done! You can now open your file %s." % user_input2)
```

Comment: I don't know...maybe they don't want you doing that. Per their Terms of usage documentation `You represent, warrant, and agree that you will not contribute or submit any User Submission (defined below) or other materials or otherwise use the Service or interact with the Service in a manner that:...`

Comment: `(h)  “Crawls,” “scrapes,” or “spiders” any page, data, or portion of or relating to the Service or Content (through use of manual or automated means);

(i)    Circumvents or attempts to circumvent any features, limitations, or restrictions of the Service (including, without limitation, attempting to access, download, export, or otherwise use or exploit any Content using any automated means or tools);`